# Change alpha after scroll part of the screen in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, scroll, android-jetpack-compose

I have this logic with which I can already change the background alpha as the user scrolls, but it's not exactly what I want. I want the alpha to start decreasing until it disappears after the user has scrolled 1.5 of the screen. How can I do this?

```
val list = mutableListOf<String>().apply {
            for (i in 0..1000) {
                add("Item $i")
            }
        }
    
        setContent {
            val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
            val visibility by remember {
                derivedStateOf {
                    when {
                        lazyListState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.isNotEmpty() && lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex == 0 -> {
                            val imageSize = lazyListState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo[0].size
                            val scrollOffset = lazyListState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
    
                            scrollOffset / imageSize.toFloat()
                        }
                        else -> 1f
                    }
                }
            }
    
            ScrollableBackgroundTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Box {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.main_background),
                        contentDescription = null,
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .graphicsLayer {
                                alpha = 1f - visibility
                            }
                    )
    
                    LazyColumn(
                        state = lazyListState
                    ) {
                        items(list.size) { index ->
                            Text(text = list[index], modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It depends on the size of the first item in the list. Also 1.5 of the screen is quite in-understandable. Do you mean 1.5 times of the screen?

Comment: @Subfly Yes, after going through 15% (1.5 times?) of the screen, it starts to hide the background, that is, to change the alpha.